# Wishlist button color on Magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, wishlist

How to set active class to magento2.1 wish-list button on product page?
I mean that, when i go to product page, if i marked that product to my wish-list before, just shows already added to wish-list or change the color of button.

Comment: For example: show red heart on products that already added to wishlist

Comment: Do you want this on product page only or in the listing page as well?

Comment: Just in product page

Comment: You can check the answer. Its working perfectly for me.

Comment: Is it working correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy the following file:

> /vendor/magento/module-wishlist/view/frontend/templates/catalog/product/view/addto/wishlist.phtml

to you desired theme like below:

> /app/design/frontend/Dapl/demo/Magento_Wishlist/templates/catalog/product/view/addto/wishlist.phtml

and add the following code to your theme's wishlist.phtml like below:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Catalog\Product\View\AddTo\Wishlist $block */
?>
<?php if ($block->isWishListAllowed()) : ?>
    <?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
    <?php $isAdded = $this->helper('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data')->getWishlistItemCollection()->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $_product->getId())->count(); ?>
    <?php if($isAdded): ?>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="action towishlist already-added" data-action="add-to-wishlist"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Added to Wish List')) ?></span></a>
    <?php else: ?>
       <a href="#" class="action towishlist" data-post='<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getWishlistParams() ?>' data-action="add-to-wishlist"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Wish List')) ?></span></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "body": {
            "addToWishlist": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getWishlistOptionsJson() ?>
        }
    }
</script>
```

Use the following css for color change or you can add any other color according to your requriement and add it to your respective css or less file.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .product-social-links .action.towishlist.already-added{color: #ff0000;}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i tried it but it adds new wish-list icon and no action. just says: javascript:void(0)

Comment: Can you update what you have tried? I think you have missed something

Comment: I just created Magento_Wishlist/templates/catalog/product/view/addto/wishlist.phtml and put your code on it  then added css to one of my CSS files related to product page. but it still has no changed color and will add to wish-list again.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot what you are seeing?

Comment: @SukumarGorai I tried your wishlist condition in vendor/magento/module-wishlist/view/frontend/templates/catalog/product/list/addto/wishlist.phtml file but it is not working. Can you check ? (Magento version 2.2.9)

Comment: Does your code support Magento commerce edition 2.4.1?

Comment: @zus I have note tested it on 2.4.1 but I think it should work on 2.4.1 as well

Comment: After update the code wishlist color not changing : https://snipboard.io/SiQA04.jpg

Comment: I am updated with your code, if i click wishlist icon the product successfully added but when i come back to see product listing page still wishlist color grey, any help thanks. I am using a custom theme inherit from a blank theme, appreciate your support. thanks.

Comment: @zus Can you check if class is added to the anchor tag or not?

Comment: @SukumarGorai yes, pls check it. https://snipboard.io/9IA6e5.jpg

Comment: @SukumarGorai FYI  PHTML : https://justpaste.it/6x3h6  CSS : https://justpaste.it/2kih0

Comment: @SukumarGorai My 2.4.1 classes are the same right? https://snipboard.io/9IA6e5.jpg

Comment: Above answer is for Product Details Page and you are working on Listing page I think. Remove .product-social-links from css and check it in Product Details Page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119581/discussion-between-zus-and-sukumar-gorai).

Comment: Still not working. i am using Magento 2.4.1 commerce edition.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who meets the same MySQL error posted by David B, please use **main_table.product_id** or cat_index.product_id to replace **product_id** in **addFieldToFilter**.

```
vendor/magento/module-wishlist/view/frontend/templates/catalog/product/view/addto/wishlist.phtml
```

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Catalog\Product\View\AddTo\Wishlist $block */
?>
<?php if ($block->isWishListAllowed()) : ?>
    <?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
    <?php $isAdded = $this->helper('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data')->getWishlistItemCollection()->addFieldToFilter('main_table.product_id', $_product->getId())->count(); ?>
    <?php if($isAdded): ?>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="action towishlist already-added" data-action="add-to-wishlist"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Added to Wish List')) ?></span></a>
    <?php else: ?>
       <a href="#" class="action towishlist" data-post='<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getWishlistParams() ?>' data-action="add-to-wishlist"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Wish List')) ?></span></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "body": {
            "addToWishlist": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getWishlistOptionsJson() ?>
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This change doesn't seem to work with M2.4.4 though it prevents the MySQL error.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @SukumarGorai look like a good solution. But with Magento 2.3 it generates a MySQL error message for the resulting query.

The query to generate isAdded produces this SQL:

SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `wishlist_item` AS `main_table`
INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index_store1` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id = main_table.product_id AND cat_index.category_id = '2' AND cat_index.visibility IN (3, 2, 4) WHERE (`wishlist_id` = '') AND (`main_table`.`store_id` IN('1')) AND (`product_id` = '4317');

The error message reports that product_id is ambiguous.

Can you suggest a way to generate isAdded that avoids this error?